# onclick event won't fire when there is more than one dynamically added button

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, web-applications, onclick

So I have EDIT and REMOVE buttons that are dynamically added for each data node (a "poll") in a Firebase database. I have a function which assigns onclick listeners to these with jQuery, but oddly, the event only fires when there just happens to be a single node, and hence a single pair of EDIT/REMOVE buttons. When there are multiple nodes and multiple pairs of buttons, none will fire. Here's the javascript where the events are added to the buttons...

```
function displayCurrentPollsForEditing(pollsRef)
{
    var tbl = createTable();
    var th = ('<th>Polls</th>');
    $(th).attr('colspan', '3');
    $(th).appendTo($(tbl).children('thead'));
    pollsRef.once('value', function(pollsSnapshot) {
        pollsSnapshot.forEach(function(pollsChild) {
            var type = pollsChild.name();
            // If this is true if means we have a poll node
            if ($.trim(type) !== "NumPolls") 
            {
                // Create variables
                var pollRef = pollsRef.child(type);
                var pollName = pollsChild.val().Name;
                var btnEditPoll = $('<button>EDIT</button>');
                var btnRemovePoll = $('<button>REMOVE</button>');
                var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
                var voterColumn = $('<td></td>');
                var editColumn = $('<td></td>');
                var rmvColumn = $('<td></td>');
                // Append text and set attributes and listeners
                $(voterColumn).text(pollName);
                $(voterColumn).attr('width', '300px');
                $(btnEditPoll).attr({
                    'class': 'formee-table-button',
                    'font-size': '1.0em'
                });
                $(btnRemovePoll).attr({
                    'class': 'formee-table-remove-button',
                    'font-size': '1.0em'
                });
                $(btnEditPoll).appendTo($(editColumn));
                $(btnRemovePoll).appendTo($(rmvColumn));
                // Append to row and row to table body
                $(tr).append(voterColumn).append(editColumn).append(rmvColumn);
                $(tr).appendTo($(tbl).children('tbody'));
                // Append table to div to be displayed
                $('div#divEditPoll fieldset#selectPoll div#appendPolls').empty();
                $(tbl).appendTo('div#divEditPoll fieldset#selectPoll div#appendPolls');
                $(btnEditPoll).click(function() {
                    displayPollEditOptions(pollRef);
                    return false;
                });
                $(btnRemovePoll).click(function() {
                    deletePoll($(this), pollsRef);
                    return false;
                });

            }
        });
    });
}
```

The markup would be something like the following...

```
<div id="divEditPoll">
            <form class="formee" action="">
                <fieldset id="selectPoll">
                    <legend>SELECT A POLL</legend>
                    <div class="formee-msg-success">
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-12-12" id="appendPolls">
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
</div>
```

EDIT - So I've switched some lines around and now I don't set the click() events until the buttons are appended to the document, so the button elements are definitely in the DOM when the click events are attached. So could this issue result from not setting id's for these buttons? That seems strange to me, since I'm using variable references rather than ids to attach the events.

Comment: when is this function displayCurrentPollsForEditing() called?

Comment: When another button is clicked.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things I would check for.

First, make sure you don't have two elements with the same id. If you do, jquery may only bind to the first, or not bind at all.

Second, make sure the element is added to the dom **before** jquery attempts to bind the click event. If the code is running asynchronously, which can easily happen if you're using ajax, then you may be trying to bind the event before creating the element. Jquery would fail to find the element then give up silently.

Comment: Hmmm ok it could easily be either in my case. Let me check, thanks.

Comment: Do you really think id may be the problem? I'm not actually using the id's to bind the event or the buttons to the document. In fact, I don't set the id's for these buttons at all, which makes me lean towards your other potential issue, since the click events are set within an asynchronous function call. What I'm wondering is how can I test programmatically if an element is loaded in the DOM and then only set an event when it is? Would an example be possible, or link? Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

you should use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically added button

Comment: it is not correct in this case since the OP is adding the event handler to each of the created buttons